# using mutli methods in one cubit with different emit in cubit (bloc)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I am building homepage that holds one cubit as following

```
cubit: class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  final HomeRepository homeRepository;

  HomeCubit(
    this.homeRepository,
  ) : super(HomeInitial());

  List<SubCatModal> mySubCat = [];
  List<SubCatModal> subCat() {
    emit(HomeLoaded());
    homeRepository.getSubCatRepository().then((respone) {
      emit(HomeSubCatSuccessCase(subCatList: respone));
      mySubCat = respone;
    });
    return mySubCat;
  }

  List<FirstSlideModal> myFirstSlider = [];
  List<FirstSlideModal> sliderListCubit() {
    emit(HomeLoaded());
    homeRepository.getFirstSliderRepository().then((respone) {
      try {
        emit(HomeFirstSliderSuccessCase(firstSliderList: respone));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(HomeErrorCase(message: respone));
      }
      myFirstSlider = respone;
    });
    return myFirstSlider;
  }
}
```

and i call the cubit and 2 methods as follwing

```
case Routes.homeScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
            create: (BuildContext context) =>
                HomeCubit(HomeRepository(homeApi: HomeApi()))..subCat()
              ..sliderListCubit(),,
            child: const Homepage(),
          ),
        );
```

and here is my code in the screen

```
 BlocBuilder<HomeCubit, HomeState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is HomeSubCatSuccessCase) {}else{text("loding")}


 BlocBuilder<HomeCubit, HomeState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is HomeFirstSliderSuccessCase) {}else{text("loding")}
```

everything works fine so far, but the problem here is **when i emit HomeFirstSliderSuccessCase the blocbulider of HomeSubCatSuccessCase goes to else "loding" so the 2 emits reflicts with eachother, so how to make them works perfeclty speartly**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you either split this up into two Cubits or merge those two functions into a larger data object to emit in a singular event.

Both `BlocBuilder` get notified of any state change you emit from `HomeCubit`, and thus both will execute `builder` again if you emit `HomeSubCatSuccessCase`. Leading to the issue you describe.

You could theoretically try to prevent a rebuild of one of the builders by leveraging `buildWhen`, but i would not recommend it.